# Canvas getImageData to RGB Values

Tags: javascript, canvas, ffmpeg

I'm currently doing the following:

From a canvas I'm getting a `50x50px` field as Pixel data with the `getImageData` function.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,50,50)
```

What I want to do, is send this data to FFMMPEG to put it together as a video, FFMPEG expects the following for RGB24:

```
AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, RGBRGB...
```

The question now is, how can I get my `ImageData` in this format so I can pipe it into FFMPEG?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for `getImageData` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

What happens is you get a `ImageData` object with a `data` attribute that contains a big array. For every pixel, there are four entries in the array, `r`, `g`, `b`, and `alpha`. So the array looks something like `[pixel1R, pixel1G, pixel1B, pixel1Alpha, ..., pixelNR, pixelNG, pixelNB, pixelNAlpha]`.

First we want to get everything into RGB format.

```
dataArray = imageData.data
rgbArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i+=4) {
    rgbArray.push([dataArray[i], dataArray[i+1], dataArray[i+2]])
}
```

Now everything is stored nicely in `rgbArray`

I'm not 100% sure about `RGB24`, but I'm pretty sure it means each entity has 24 bits, which means each R/G/B has a byte each, which is nice because that's already what the values range from. Now we just need to pack them.

```
rgb24Array = rgbArray.map(function(rgbList){
    return (rgbList[0] << 16) | (rgbList[1] << 8) | (rgbList[2])
})
```

That code will shift red by two bytes, green by one, and then `or` the values together

Pretty sure this should work

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, looks good, excuse me that i can try it not until tomorrow, but then I'll get back to it.

Comment: Was able to test it before, i get values like 11261927, which is the rgb value then. But something doesn't seem to be right, 1. ist only 8 digits not 9 and I can't seem to find any plausible explanation for the 9 on it (at that location)

Comment: thats because not every rgb value has 3 digits each.. so the shifting is wrong then too...

Comment: The length of the number isn't fixed. Imagine if you had a RGB of `(0, 0, 0)`. Then the value of the integer would be `0`. It can vary. Also, what values did you test it with?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the packing works. If I had an RGB of (1, 1, 1), the RGB24 would not be `001001001` although it seems intuitive.

If we expressed it like that, the biggest number we'd have is `255255255`, which is 9 digits long and very inefficient. From a mathematical point of view, the amount of three 1-byte numbers we can have is 256^3, which is `16777215`, which is a lot less than `255255255`. This is why we pack - so the computer can store the number more efficiently

Comment: Okay, but you think it will work anyway? I tested ike lightblue, black and green

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work. Black should yield a value of 0, _pure_ green (0, 255, 0) should yield a value of 65280, lightblue is super subjective so I can't really say what that should be.

Comment: Okay, I got it I guess, I'll try to parse it into ffmpeg tomorrow then, thank you

Comment: Would be much quicker and use much less memory if you do `var b24Bit = new Uint32Buffer(imageData.data.buffer); var i=0; while(i < b24Bit.length) { b24Bit[i++] &= 0xFFFFFF }`

Comment: It'd probably be faster, and I like your idea of using buffers, but also your code doesn't work - read my note at the top of my answer about how the data is stored in `ImageData.data`

Comment: @mjkaufer Tried it now. Unfortunatelly, I still get the error saying invalid data. I just put the stroke style like this `ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";`, so on pure green, and you're right, the output is 65280. I set `pix_fmt` on the `ffmpegArgs` to `rgb24`, so this should be the right one to go with as well. But it's not working, still getting that "invalid data" Type error...

Comment: @mjkaufer Figured one thing out: http://kylecordes.com/2007/pipe-ffmpeg there you can read, that ffmpeg doesn't seem to accept pure rgb data (een if the option is available, don't know if its really true) but however - do you know how to convert it into yuv420 instead of rgb?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you need flat array of bytes.

Javascript does not do 24 bit words so you will have to convert it to an array of bytes and just skip the alpha channel.

```
const rgb24 = new Uint8Array((imageData.data.length / 4) * 3);
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
while( i < imageData.data.length){
    rgb24[j++] = imageData.data[i++];
    rgb24[j++] = imageData.data[i++];
    rgb24[j++] = imageData.data[i++];
    i++;
}
```